# How to deal with my Mac's memory be eaten up?

Tags: macos, memory

My Macbook Pro's memory is eaten up by some programs and running slow even after restarting it.
Do you have any command or tool to check which program occupies so much memory? 
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use "Activate Monitor" on Mac or use command "top" to grep the programs which takes large memory.

Answer (score 0):

Two options come to mind:

1. Activity Monitor app that comes with macOS/OSX. See https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT201464.
2. Use the `top` command from the command line (Terminal app). See the `man` page for `top` by typing `man top`.